# How can I check in JQuery if a page is displayed in print mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At first I would like to point out, that I am not a JQuery person, I am just beginning my work with it forced by the fact that our front-end guy is sick. please be delicate with me:)

In our application we switch to view mode by changing part of the url:

- .../**view**/rest/.... means normal mode,
- .../**print**/rest/... means print mode (site is stripped, different CSS applied).

I would like to check in javascript in which mode I currently am. We use JQuery in out project.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a simple string search on `window.location.pathname`:

```
var isPrint = window.location.pathname.indexOf("/print/") > -1;
```

- /view/rest

  ```
  alert(isPrint); // -> false
  ```
- /print/rest

  ```
  alert(isPrint); // -> true
  ```

You can also perform a split and check a specific subfolder:

```
var folders = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var isPrint = folders[1] == "print";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the current URL by referencing `location.href` in your JavaScript code and determine it that way (no jQuery required).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var inPrint = (document.URL.indexOf("/print/") != -1);
```

(as long as there are no other /print/ folders)